# "\r" and "\n" are not being replaced by any method attempted in c# in a string read in from a file

Tags: c#, json, replace, newline

I have a file with JSON in it, I Use: `File.ReadAllText(file)` to read it in, the I attempt to replace all instances of "\r" and "\n" but everything I have tried will not remove those. Here is what I have tried:

```
Replace("\r\n", " ").Replace("\n", " ").Replace("\r", " ")
Replace("\r", " ").Replace("\n", " ")
Replace("\n", " ").Replace("\r", " ")
Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ").
Join(" ", Regex.Split(str, @"(?:\r\n|\n|\r)"))
Regex.Replace(str, @"\r\n?|\n", " ")
Regex.Replace(str, "(\"(?:[^\"\\\\]|\\\\.)*\")|\\s+", "$1")
```

I have even attempted Split the string by "\r", "\n", "\r\n" to no avail.

And lastly I tried to convert the string to plain ascii encoding then read it back in and tried the replacements and still nothing.

I also tried converting the file to ANSI encoding and still the replacements did not work.

The reason for removing these new lines is the json has to be very clean for downstream usage.

The file is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5DAOlJz-7TUSGtKMEFmN2hoTkU/view?usp=sharing

It is just a JSON string in the file.

Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT: I should say that I did get it to work in one manner; by assigning the string as a static variable in VS and doing standard replace. But that is not workable.

Comment: Have you tried with UTF8 encoding if applicable?

Comment: *Why* does it have to be "very clean"? Newlines are valid Json characters. If some system downstream can't handle newlines, they have a bug and can't handle Json. Expect more bugs in the future. Also, what do you mean that you can't remove them? Are you checking the result of `Replace` or did you expect `Replace` to somehow modify the original string?

Comment: @ Mladen Oršolić: It is in UTF8 to begin with

Comment: @user1013388 it doesn't matter. .NET uses Unicode. Please post some *actual* code. For example, if you write `var newString=original.Replace("\r").Replace("\n");`, the result will be a single line

Comment: yes I am checking the result string not the original. And the requirement is that the string be void of linefeeds, etc...

Comment: you're seeing literal `\n` in the json text? maybe you should be trying `Replace('\\n'...)`

Comment: That file doesn't contain any newlines. What are you trying to do??

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: The code is above, i read in the file the used the various replace methods.

Comment: @user1013388 that's not the *actual* code. The code you posted won't compile anywhere.

Comment: @user1013388 well, you can't replace any newlines if there aren't any to begin with. The linked file doesn't contain any newlines

Comment: @MarcB: Oh I hadn't thought of that. Let me try it.

Comment: @MarcB: YES!! That was it. Thanks bro!

Answer (score 0):

it usually works like this :

```
string someString = yourString.Replace("\r\n", "");
```

replace doesnt replace stuff in string it self without explicit assignment.

edit :
As i can see your [file](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=a08d670d3f9ff0845a34263361d0ab6b) contains literally `\n\r\n` which are actually not line breaks so this should work :

```
string someString = yourString.Replace(@"\n\r\n", "");
```

This should give you cleaner json file.

Comment: MarcB had the answer above, it turns out they were not real new lines, but literal ones, they were throwing me for a loop. But I appreciate your help, thank you!